# How to implement signInWithEmailAndPassword method of firebase as cloud function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am currently building an app with vue/firebase. But I eventually want to switch to AWS in the future. So I don't want to use the register or sign in method of firebase in my frontend project so that it will be easier to switch to AWS.

How can I implement the same functionality of signInWithEmailAndPassword and createUserWithEmailAndPassword as cloud functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating users from a Cloud function using Admin SDK ([`createUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user)) is technically same as users signing up using client SDK from your web app since they both create user accounts in Firebase Authentication.

I'm not what you mean by *'switch to AWS'*, but if that's referring to using any other authentication system e.g. AWS Amplify in this case, then you can just [export users from Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export) and then create user accounts in the new auth provider.

Comment: Ah I understand that there is createUser() functionality but does that auto authenticate users with token/cookie such as it does with the signInWith methods?

Comment: @AhmetYazıcı you would have to explicitly login users on your  web app using the client SDK. In that case it makes more sense to sign up users using the client SDK using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` like methods.